# Configure Lighttpd to call FastCGI app if static file does not exist

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

How do I configure Lighttpd to call the FastCGI application if no static file exists at the specified path?
The FastCGI module in Lighttpd supports the configuration option "check-local". If it is set to "enable", Lighttpd will check whether the requested file exists in the document root or not. It will return the file if it exists or responds with a 404 error. However, the FastCGI app does not get executed, if the file does not exist.

I want to implement the following scenario:

- User requests /images/example.jpg
- Image exists => Return the image
- Image does not exist => Generate the image with the FastCGI app

I am using the following configuration in Lighttpd:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
$HTTP["host"] == "localhost" {
    fastcgi.server += ( "/" =>
        ((
            "bin-path" => "/path/to/fcgi/app",
            "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/foobar.socket",
            "max-procs" => 8,
            "check-local" => "disable"
        ))
    )
}
```

**Edit:**
I just found a workaround. Maybe there is a better solution?

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
server.modules += ( "mod_rewrite" )
$HTTP["host"] == "localhost" {
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^(.*)$" => "$1?create=true"
    )
    $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "create=true" {
        fastcgi.server += ( "/" =>
            ((
                "bin-path" => "/path/to/fcgi/app",
                "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/foobar.socket",
                "max-procs" => 8,
                "check-local" => "disable"
            ))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the querystring solution looks good. However make sure you use a querystring with a little more entropy than create=true, for example beyelerimage=generate. I added this as a comment as its not really an answer more of a tip.